# is it possible to pass multiple values in View without new class?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I wanna ask is it possible to pass multiple values to the SharedLayout View without generating new class?

for example
I fill my shared layout at the begining with a list of categories and products each time. I pass them using `Tuple<object1, object2>` but Tuple has max 6 objects, and in my app I will have to pass for then 6... but i don't want to generate new class that contains List of products, categories, users, etc...
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Using `ViewModel` is the best practice to pass data to the view and you seem to have the perfect candidate for using it, but if you don't want to, and if you are already using `Tuple` there is a way to pass more than 7 parameters to tuple by nesting  tuples inside of tuples.

If you look at the `Tuple` definition:

```
Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TRest>
```

the last element of the 8-tuple is the generic type parameter `Rest` that represents any generic `Tuple` object that defines the types of the tuple's remaining components.

That gives you the possibility to create tuples with as many parameters as you want.

Consider this 16-tuple for an example:

```
Tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, 
     Tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, 
     Tuple<int, int>>> t16;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create strongly-typed views using an interface rather than a class. Then you can pass any object to your view as long as it's type implements that interface.

Comment: He explicitly doesn't want to create a view model.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the ViewBag.

```
ViewBag.Products = productList;
```

In your view

```
@foreach(var product in (ProductList)ViewBag.Products) {
  Html.DisplayFor(x => product);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about Session and TempData.

Comment: Your code is not valid, you should cast ViewBag.Products before using

Comment: Still is not valid, now your forgot ';' after Html.DisplayFor

Comment: @Alexander you don't need it, and I'm also not a compiler, the code is there to give an idea how to proceed, not to give someone exactly what to copy and paste into their IDE.

Comment: @Alexander This is a site for professional developers; if they are confused by a compiler telling them exactly what they problem is, a SO answer is the least of their problems.